# How to add authorization header dynamically in a retrofit request using annontation?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Actually I'm using Retrofit 2 in my Android application (I'm using Kotlin) and I want to execute a post request like below :

```
@Headers("Authorization: Bearer: $Constants.TOKEN")
@POST("/task")
fun createTask(object:Object)
```

The request work perfectly when it comes that the token is a constant, but I want it to be dynamic.

After many search I found the solutions like below :

```
@POST("/task")
fun createTask(@Header("Authorization: Bearer") authorization:String, object:Object)
```

OR

```
@POST("/task")
fun createTask(@HeaderMap header:Map<String, String>, object:Object)
```

When I try it, I got error like :

```
bad request : error at char 0x20
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem, but then I tried something like:

```
@POST("/task")
fun createTask(@Header("Authorization") authorization, object:Object)
```

And append `Bearer` to your token that you're passing, like

```
createTask("Bearer ".plus(access_token))
```

Also it seems like the extra colon `:` you're adding is causing the error, removing the colon might also work.

Comment: Removing the ":" didn't work, but your first solution is the best .. Really greatfull !!

Answer (score 3):

To make header dynamic I use Header-interceptor while using Retrofit,

```
class HeaderInterceptor: Interceptor {

/**
 * Interceptor class for setting of the dynamic headers for every request
 */
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var request = chain.request()
    request = request?.newBuilder()
            // dynamic token you get should be use instead of #YOUR_DYNAMIC_TOKEN.
            ?.addHeader("Authorization: Bearer", #YOUR_DYNAMIC_TOKEN)  
            ?.build()
    return chain.proceed(request)
}
```

}

Now we can use it like below

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun getOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
     val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
     interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
     val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
     builder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor())                
     return builder.build()
```

}

---

or Simply we can use it directly like :

```
@Provides
  @Singleton
  fun getOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization: Bearer", #YOUR_DYNAMIC_TOKEN)
                            .build()
                    chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }
  }
```